# improving algorithm which aligns a face with an affine transform

Tags: c++, opencv, face-detection

In my program I capture portraits at various parts of the screen which then I want to align so that the resulting images all have the eyes, mouths and noses at the same location (eyes should be perfectly aligned, the rest as much as possible). I can tolerate some stretching/skewing if it's not extreme or too evident.

Currently I am using Haar Cascades to track faces/eyes and store the three rectangles them in a Face struct. Then I use this code to align the image:

```
void helper::opencv::allign_and_isolate_face(cv::Mat& photo, helper::opencv::Face& face) {

  // detect the center of the eyes and the center of the face
  const cv::Point2f left_eye {face.left_eye.x + static_cast<float>(face.left_eye.width) / 2,
      face.left_eye.y + static_cast<float>(face.left_eye.height) / 2};
  const cv::Point2f right_eye {face.right_eye.x + static_cast<float>(face.right_eye.width) / 2,
      face.right_eye.y + static_cast<float>(face.right_eye.height) / 2};
  const cv::Point2f center_of_the_face {face.face.x + static_cast<float>(face.face.width) / 2,
      face.face.y + static_cast<float>(face.face.height) / 2};

  // calculate the affine trasform matrix
  cv::Point2f source_points[3] { left_eye, right_eye, center_of_the_face };
  float l_eye_pct {0.33};
  float r_eye_pct {0.66};
  float eyes_level_pct {0.4};
  static cv::Point2f destination_points[3] = { 
    cv::Point2f{static_cast<float>(properties::captured_image_width) * l_eye_pct, 
        static_cast<float>(properties::captured_image_height) * eyes_level_pct},
    cv::Point2f{static_cast<float>(properties::captured_image_width) * r_eye_pct,
        static_cast<float>(properties::captured_image_height) * eyes_level_pct},
    cv::Point2f{static_cast<float>(properties::captured_image_width)/2,
        static_cast<float>(properties::captured_image_height)/2}
  };
  auto warp_mat = cv::getAffineTransform( source_points, destination_points );

  // apply the transform and crop
  cv:: warpAffine(photo, photo, warp_mat,
           cv::Size(properties::captured_image_width,properties::captured_image_height));
}
```

The algorithm selects three points in the original image (the centres of the two eyes and the "middle" of the face) and compares them with the locations these elements should be in the destination image (always in the same position) to calculate an affine matrix. Yet this approach has several problems and I'm seeking way to make it better:

- how can I calculate more accurately the position of the eyes and of some other point in the face (centre of noise/mouth maybe?) ? Using landmark detection might be a solution to this - but I don't have relevant experience, some example would be highly appreciated.
- My algorithm will sometimes result in highly distorted images
- While the eyes are always aligned, the nose and mouth are not.

thanks in advance.

Comment: Check out the [DeepFace](http://www.cv-foundation.org/openaccess/content_cvpr_2014/html/Taigman_DeepFace_Closing_the_2014_CVPR_paper.html) paper, particularly section 2. They talk about a very similar approach. Or for a basic affine homography, you can use the 4 point algorithm. Note: any homography requires a minimum of 4 2D points.